# peewee assign str to CharField raises incompatible type error

Tags: python-3.x, peewee, pylance

There are many places where one wants to assign a `str` to `CharField`. But that raises below type error.

```
Cannot assign member "uri" for type "MyTable"
  Expression of type "str" cannot be assigned to member "uri" of class "MyTable"
    "str" is incompatible with "CharField" Pylance(reportGeneralTypeIssues)
```

Well, we can suppress it by adding `# type: ignore` hint, but what is the proper way ( or type safe way for the type checker) to assign a string to `CharField`?

I was hoping for something like `CharField.valueOf("str")` available in the framework, but then its an overkill and adds to the execution time!

The case is same with other types too, for example assigning `True/False` to a `BooleanField` .

Comment: I can't speak to what pylance is doing, but Peewee makes use of metaclasses and descriptors for models and fields, respectively. This all plays well with Python's strongly dynamic nature.